# Eclipse IDE predefined variable for current class

Tags: eclipse, code-snippets, predefined-variables

I have a logger defined for every Java class:

```
private XLogger logger = XLoggerFactory
        .getXLogger(AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl.class.getName());
```

I want to add this to Eclipse snippets. Is there a pre-defined Eclipse variable such that the class name could be dynamically replaced with the class name where this snippet is inserted?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using this:

```
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(${enclosing_type}.class);
```

Define it in Java->Editor->Templates of the Eclipse Preferences.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, you can add imports.

```
${imp:import(org.slf4j.Logger, org.slf4j.LoggerFactory)}
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class);
```